# mysql Trigger issue in wrong schema

Tags: mysql, triggers

What does **Trigger in wrong schema** mean ?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `wordpress_database1`.`insert_user_from_database2` AFTER INSERT ON `wordpress_database2`.`wp_users`
FOR EACH
ROW
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO `wordpress_database1`.`wp_users` ( ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename,  user_email, user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name)
    VALUES ( New.ID, New.user_login, New.user_pass, New.user_nicename, New.user_email, New.user_url, New.user_registered, New.user_activation_key, New.user_status, New.display_name );
END;$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trigger needs to be on the same schema as where you are inserting (i.e. you would create the trigger on `wordpress_database2`).  You can still insert to other schemas.  With that simple change, the entire rest of it should work.

Answer (score 0):

This would have been helpful to me: [Difference between Schema and Database in MySQL?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-schema-and-database-in-mysql):

I quote: *"In MySQL, schema is synonymous with database."*.

They are just words, but if you're unaware of this the error message can be confusing.