# MySQL: Trigger in wrong schema

Tags: mysql, triggers

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `range` BEFORE INSERT ON touristCompany.hotels
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.star >5 THEN
            SET NEW.star = 5;
        ELSEIF NEW.star < 1 THEN
            SET NEW.star = 1;
        END IF;

    END;//
delimiter ;
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql Trigger issue in wrong schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823033/mysql-trigger-issue-in-wrong-schema)

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't crate the trigger : "Trigger issue is wrong schema"

Comment: star is the column name of touristCompany.hotels

Comment: Please state your question/problem *clearly* in your question so that it is more visible to users.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the trigger within the same schema/database where the insert operation is happening. From your trigger definition it's obvious that trigger operation will be under `touristCompany` database. Make sure you are creating the trigger under same database.

Modify your trigger definition like below

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `touristCompany`.`range` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `touristCompany`.`hotels`
FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.star > 5 THEN
            SET NEW.star = 5;
        ELSEIF NEW.star < 1 THEN
            SET NEW.star = 1;
        END IF;

    END;//
delimiter ;
```

(OR) Select the database before creating trigger

```
USE `touristCompany`;

delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `range` ...
<rest of code here>
```

Comment: thanx !!!  the 2nd  choice  really work! i just test by myself, and its worked )))) then i google  why this happens ) )